# Definition for rule 'eslint-plugin-import/namespace' was not found in Next ESLint

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

When I run the command `npx eslint .` on my NextJS, I am getting the following error

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.56.0

TypeError: object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
Occurred while linting /src/app/api/accounts/[path]/route.ts:1
Rule: "import/namespace"
    at new Set (<anonymous>)
    at makeValidExtensionSet (/src/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/ignore.js:23:16)
    at validExtensions (/src/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/ignore.js:17:15)
    at hasValidExtension (/src/node_modules/eslint-module-utils/ignore.js:59:10)
    at ExportMap.for (/src/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:805:38)
    at ExportMap.get (/src/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/ExportMap.js:801:465)
    at processBodyStatement (/src/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/namespace.js:11:40)
    at /src/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/namespace.js:84:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Program (/src/node_modules/eslint-plugin-import/lib/rules/namespace.js:84:18)
```

This is the file `middleware.ts` which is generating the error

```
export const urls = {
    cohortListing: 'http://lp-backend:8000/api/cohorts/',
    userLogin: 'http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/login',
    verifyToken: 'http://lp-backend:8000/api/accounts/verify-token',
};
```

When I hover over  the 1st line inthe above file on  VSCode it says, **Definition for rule 'eslint-plugin-import/namespace' was not found.**

I have the following configuration in my Next JS Project

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    "extends": ["next/core-web-vitals","eslint:recommended","next", "prettier", "airbnb","plugin:import/recommended"],
    "plugins": ["prettier", "import"],
    "settings": {
        "import/extensions":{
            "extensions":[".js",".jsx",".ts",".tsx"]
        },
        "import/ignore":[".ts",".tsx"]
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
        "jsx-quotes": "off",
        "no-tabs": "off",
        "indent": "off",
        "react/jsx-indent": "off",
        "react/jsx-indent-props": "off",
        "object-curly-newline": "off",
        "import/named":2,
        "import/no-cycle":2
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea on why I am facing this error, any answer is much appreciated.